Include all subclasses in mkdocstrings
I have a python package where there is a parent class (let's call it ParentClass) from which many other classes inherit. I want to create documentation using mkdocs and mkdocstrings, specifically for those classes that inherit from ParentClass. The file structure is roughly as follows:

my_package.features.childclass1.ChildClass1, my_package.features.childclass2.ChildClass2, etc
my_package.features.mixins.ParentClass

However, the features folder also contains subfolders with classes that do not inherit from ParentClass
Is there a way to let mkdocstrings automatically render documentation only from those classes that inherit from ParentClass?

If these subclasses follow a naming pattern, you could use filters so that mkdocstrings-python only picks up these classes and nothing else when injecting the docs for the relevant modules.
A more brutal option would be to write a Griffe extension to only keep the classes you're interested in in the final object tree.
Yet another solution would be to use Markdown Exec and Griffe together to programmatically inject docs for specific classes:
Some Markdown contents.

```python exec="1" idprefix=""
import griffe

pkg_api = griffe.load("my_package")
parent_cls = pkg_api["features.mixins.ParentClass"]
for mod in pkg_api["features"].modules.values():
    for cls in mod.classes.values():
        if parent_cls in cls.resolved_bases:
            print(f"::: {cls.path}\n")
```

(not tested, might need tweaks)
We could consider adding friendlier API like cls.subclasses to get all subclasses of a class at once. Feel free to open issues on our bug tracker on GitHub. Also check out our API reference.
